# Angular 2 can't find default router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a simple router:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path     : "",
        component: AuthLayoutComponent
    },
    {
        path     : "**",
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

All time I see PageNotFoundComponent. If remove "**" router then I see an error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
```

Module:

```
@NgModule({
              declarations: [
                  MainComponent,
                  components
              ],
              imports     : [
                  routing,
                  BrowserModule
              ],
              providers   : [
                  appRoutingProviders
              ],
              bootstrap   : [MainComponent]
          })
```

Comment: Looks good. Can you add the code where you register your routes?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const routes = [
    {
        path     : "",
        pathMatch: 'full';  <<<<==== added
        component: AuthLayoutComponent
    },
    {
        path     : "**",
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Without `pathMatch: 'full'` the router continues searching for child routes with an empty path after `''` matched.